# How to obtain number of messages in clustered queue in JBoss EAP6/HornetQ

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq, jboss-eap-6, jboss-mdb

I am trying to count messages in HornetQ clustered queue on JBoss EAP 6.4 (domain mode)

Obtaining number of messages in particular HornetQ instance is not an problem ([here](http://jeefix.com/managing-hornetq-queues-via-jms-api/) is the way I do it), but what I am actually want, is to get cumulative/total number of messages of given queue in **whole cluster**.

Right now when I send to given queue **24604** messages, they are being nicely distributed to 3 nodes:

- Node A: **8201 messages**
- Node B: **8202 messages**
- Node C: **8201 messages**

Is there a way to count all messages of given queue in a cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution to obtain total number of messages in cluster by invoking broadcast ejb call on all cluster members, where each cluster member gets number of messages from InVm jms sender.

I have described it here:

1. http://jeefix.com/how-to-invoke-broadcast-ejb-at-all-jboss-eap6-ejb-cluster-members/
2. http://jeefix.com/managing-hornetq-queues-via-jms-api/